# "No files matched the search pattern" in tfs build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, tfs, asp.net-core-mvc, tfvc

I want to build my project from TFS Azure(VSTS).
I have made one project which is under Asp.Net Core.

I have made Build definition with Asp.Net Core Template and given the path for restore like `**\*.csproj` but I am not sure about this path or not?

I have tried many options like `**\admis.csproj` and some others, but I have faced the same error as the one on the following image:

[image]

I am using Asp.Net Core 2.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any CSPROJ files downloaded in the `Get Sources` step?

Comment: I think No CSPROJ file downloaded in the step of Get Sources only display at last "All files are up to date"

Answer (score 1):

Just check your `Workspace mappings` in `Get sources` step, make sure you have mapped the source directory which included the solution or project file `*.csproj`:

[image]

Comment: Thans for your response, No sir i have followed the same instruction that you have given.It gives me error in Restore section "No Files matched the search pattern" . I have given the full path of .CSPROJ file and given also an *\.csproj file but it gives same error

Comment: @VickyBhatt You need to make sure that the `*.csproj` file is existing under the directory you selected. Then check the get source step to make sure the files are downloaded to the agent server.... Besides, the default search pattern should be `**/*.csproj` but not `**\*.csproj`. So just have a try for that.

Comment: @@VickyBhatt Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update? If you still have the issue, please capture screenshot for your build definition settings, also share the logs on getting sources for troubleshoot. Whatever you need to make sure you have the  `*.csproj` file in sources...

Comment: thanks for response but i have tried all the things so i have sent you a screen shots for whole process this will help you [TFS Screenshots](https://loudshark.blob.core.windows.net/vicksindustries/Misc/Internal/Error/TFS%20Error.zip) please give some more idea thanks

Comment: @VickyBhatt Just try mapping to `$/AD Internal 2017/Admins2016v2/Src/Admins2016.Web` then check it again. Also share the logs on getting sources step, it the sources are not downloaded, then the system will also can not find the `*.csproj` files.  Suggest creating a new build definition to check it again.

Comment: I am trying both the way generated new build but no positive result I really don't know where i am doing wrong i have attached screen shots of [getresourceLog](https://loudshark.blob.core.windows.net/vicksindustries/Misc/Internal/Error/gettingResoucesLog.JPG)

Comment: @VickyBhatt Seems the files are not downloaded. Set `system.debug = true`, then share the get sources logs here for troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Please check!

1) Server path should be: $/YourDevOpsProjectName/YourBranchName/TheRestPathUntil .csproj file

As I see on your screenshot, your path should be **$/0424Test/NetCoreApp/NetCoreApp** (I'm assuming that your **.csproj** file is there).

2) I had the same problem, because when I tried to Queue build for my project, in Source version I set 1 and the process of the queue tried to take 1 source code version, that of course not exists. 
[image]

If Source version's value is empty, it try to get the last version of your source code

3) Use **/*.csproj as "Path to project(s)" for every task in your Agent job.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Please check!

1. Server path should be: $/YourDevOpsProjectName/YourBranchName/TheRestPathUntil .csproj file

Comment: Please do not copy other answers and repost them!